# After upgrading Kafka, 'Newest' and 'Oldest' does not work properly for Kafka tool

Tags: apache-kafka

I have upgraded kafka broker from 0.8.2.1 to 0.10.2.0. Everything is fine with Kafka's functionality, but Kafka tool is not working as expected.

When I select 'Newest' or 'oldest', I am unable to see any data and an error message is shown, as below:
[Newest or Oldest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVrUj.png)

But, the tool works fine when I select 'From Specific Offset' and data is displayed.

I observed that in the 'Properties' of the topic, Start offset and End Offset is '-1', which was not the case before upgrading. The image below displays the same thing:
[Start and End Offsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqYU4.png)

Is it because of start and end offsets that data is not getting displayed in the Kafka tool through Newest and Oldest ?

Comment: What is "Kafka tool"?

Comment: Kafka Tool is a GUI application for managing and using Apache Kafka clusters. Please visit http://www.kafkatool.com/ for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using **Kafka Tool 1.0.2** and had the same problem. Here is what solved it for me:

- Open Kafka Tool and click on the connection while it is still disconnected
- Change the *Kafka Cluster Version* to match what is on the server (0.10 in your case)
- Click the *Update* button
- Now connect, and the *Refresh* and *Retrieve* buttons should now function as expected

See screenshot: [Changing the Kafka Cluster Version in Kafka Tool 1.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP8bK.png)